# Why on Android fopen returns permisson denied error?

Tags: android, c, android-manifest, fopen

The Android application I created tries to read a file:

```
FILE* file = fopen("/storage/emulated/0/test.txt", "r");
```

Unfortunatelly, `file` pointer is null, and `errno` is set to 13, which is `permission denied` error code.

The file exists, because I created it and `adb shell cat "/storage/emulated/0/test.txt"` succesfully prints the content.

The application is created entirely in C, there is only one method annotated with `JNIEXPORT`:

```
JNIEXPORT
void ANativeActivity_onCreate(ANativeActivity 
    *activity, void *savedState, size_t savedStateSize) { ... }
```

I was following [this project](https://github.com/cnlohr/rawdrawandroid) on how to write an Android app in C. Apart from reading the file it works.

Below is the Android Manifest file, with permissions set:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<manifest xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="org.mypackage.vocabulary">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="30" android:targetSdkVersion="30"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_RELEASE_APP"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <application 
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:hasCode="false"
        android:label="vocabulary"
        tools:replace="android:icon,android:theme,android:allowBackup,label"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/icon">
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:label="vocabulary"
            android:name="android.app.NativeActivity">
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name" android:value="vocabulary"/>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

When I install the app, in the settings for this app I set `Storage permission` to `Allow access to media only`.

**Why fopen does not open the file**?

Comment: Android version of used device?

Comment: `Allow access to media only.` Do you consider a .txt file media?

Comment: @blackapps that was the only option available in the `Storage permission` settings. Android version is 11

Comment: On Android 11+ devices your app has no access to that location. You could put the file in the public Documents directory instead. Your app has access to that location but only for files it created itself.

Comment: @blackapps Documents directory worked, thanks!

Comment: @blackapps, if an app created a directory, is it possible to set permissions in such a way, that I can create files in that directory (e.g. using adb shell), and the app would be able to read them, because they are in the directory that the app has created?

Comment: MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE or let the user pick the file or your subdirectory using SAF.